# Avoiding Empty Entry

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, swift

Guys how to avoid adding an empty items to a toDoList table ?  I've been busy with building a toDo list and came to a problem when a user doesn't fill anything in the textfield but he can still add the empty item to the table, and when I try to swipe the table's row with an empty entry I get a fatal error ! why is that and how to avoid adding those empty data ?

OK, I added your code to my add Button : But it didn't help that much!

```
@IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {  
    if "" != item.text {
        // DO Something but don't fill the row (**item** is my text field)
        toDoList.append(item.text)
        item.text = ""

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(toDoList, forKey: "toDoList")

    }else{
         labelField.text = "Please enter an item!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method that you add your item just check the text property of your UITextField instance and if it contains string then add the item

```
if "" != textField.text {
}
```

Though using the solution I gave has some drawbacks such as user can just enter space as its input but it does the job. You can also use regular expression too in order to restrict the input you want user enters.

Comment: `@""` is Objective-C, not Swift :)

Comment: @MartinR Oh yeah, my bad, wrote it fast

Answer (score 0):

you can control the input of an item like this

```
if "" == textField.text {
// DO Something but don't fill the row
}
```

and for , the swipe problem, you can implement the following Method

```
optional func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 
    if commitEditingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row, and the item in the array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, Fixed it! That's how I did it :

```
if item.text != "" {
        // DO Something but don't fill the row

     toDoList.append(item.text)
}else{

    labelField.text = "Please enter an item!"
    }
```

Comment: I may want to be in before you get other errors, what would happen if a users enters a space? Do you want to remind them of a space?